# Shared steps and cloning

Tags: clone, microsoft-test-manager, cloning

This question is about shared steps management via the user interface in Microsoft test manager VSTS2013 and/or online via the visualstudio.com version.

Say we have a bunch of test cases with some shared steps and we clone (/deep copy, not just 'copy') the test plan. The result is that all shared steps in the test cases are also cloned, which I would expect -- so no question so far.

But, when I then go to a test case and I want to add shared steps to it, the query to locate the shared steps will show all instances of a shared step (assume I am searching by Title). *How can I now make the distinction which instance of the shared steps is the right one to choose for the Test plan that my test case is in?*

If I choose just any one of them I'll for sure end up with test cases from one test plan linked to shared steps in another test plan, and that sounds like something we would not want (right?).

Any light on how to properly manage test cases versus their shared steps is welcome!

Thank you,
Bill.

Answer (score 0):

If your (cloned) testplan is defined under a certain iteration, e.g., Project Y\Release X, and you insert a shared step, a query is opened. There you need to add an extra clause (with an And) with as Field: "Iteration Path" and Operator "Under" The Value is for this example "Release X".
Hope this helps.